# Am I allowed to use an interface as a variable in an enum?

Tags: java, enums, interface

I am trying to use an interface as a variable in an enum:

Example interface

```java
public interface TestInterface {

void printMessage();

}
```

A class implementing the interface

```java
public class TestClass implements Test {

 @Override
    public void printMessage() {

        System.out.println("This is a test");

    }

}
```

Then we have the enum

```java
public enum TestEnum {

TEST1(TestClass);

private final TestInterface interface;

TestEnum(TestInterface interface) {
   this.interface = interface;
}

}
```

Just a quick example. I am trying something similar and it doesn't allow me to use the class implementing the interface as the value in the enum. I have searched on google and cannot find anything on this.

Am I even allowed to do this? It is my understanding that I can use the class since it implements the interface? Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You can use an _object_ of that class, but you can't use the class itself.  `TEST1(new TestClass())` ought to work.

Comment: try `TEST1(new TestClass());`

Comment: You're using the keyword `interface` as the name of a variable; you'll need to change that name.  Also, I assume you meant that `TestClass implements TestInterface`.

Comment: new TestClass() worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

An enum in Java is a class, specifically a subclass of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html), for which objects are automatically instantiated and assigned to names determined at compile-time.

- An enum can implement an interface. This means each object instantiated and named in the enum offers that method.
- An enum can be made to hold a reference to an object of an interface, this reference being a member variable on each of its named instances.

Let's look at each of these.

## Enum implementing an interface

Yes, an enum can implement an interface. As with any other class, define using `implements` keyword and implement the necessary methods.

Say we have an interface `Animal` with a single method `speak`.

```
package work.basil.example;

public interface Animal
{
    String speak();
}
```

We can make an enum that implements that interface. That means all of the named objects of that enum class offer that behavior.

```
package work.basil.example;

public enum GrannyPet implements Animal
{
    // Enum objects, automatically instantiated when this class loads.
    TWEETY(),
    SYLVESTER(),
    HECTOR();

    @Override
    public String speak ()
    {
        return "talk";
    }
}
```

Let's try that behavior by calling the method on each of the enum instances.

```
    Set < GrannyPet > grannyPets = EnumSet.allOf( GrannyPet.class );
    for ( GrannyPet grannyPet : grannyPets )
    {
        System.out.println( "Granny’s pet: " + grannyPet + " says: " + grannyPet.speak() );
    }
```

Output.

> Granny’s pet: TWEETY says: talk
>
> Granny’s pet: SYLVESTER says: talk
>
> Granny’s pet: HECTOR says: talk

But I do not think this is what you meant.

## Enum referring to objects of an interface

I suspect you want an enum whose objects each refer to an object of a particular class.

Yes we can do this. An enum in Java can have a constructor method, and that constructor can take arguments. So we can pass an object of your desired interface to the constructor for each enum object being instantiated. This all happens automatically when the enum class is loaded, as with any enum.

### `Animal`

Let's use the same interface, `Animal`.

```
package work.basil.example;

public interface Animal
{
    String speak();
}
```

Let's define three classes implementing that interface, `Bird`, `Cat`, and `Dog`.

### `Bird`

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Bird implements Animal
{

    @Override
    public String speak ()
    {
        return "chirp";
    }
}
```

### `Cat`

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Cat implements Animal
{
    @Override
    public String speak ()
    {
        return "meow";
    }
}
```

### `Dog`

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Dog implements Animal
{
    @Override
    public String speak ()
    {
        return "bark";
    }
}
```

### `GrannyPet` enum

Revise our enum have a constructor taking an argument of an `Animal`. Store that `Animal` object in a member variable.

So now the `GrannyPet` enum does not *implement* the interface `Animal`, it holds an object of type `Animal`.

Compare this code to the enum code above, noticing how TWEETY, SYLVESTER, and HECTOR each take an argument here while using empty `()` parens above. So,  `TWEETY()` versus `TWEETY( new Bird() )`.

```
package work.basil.example;

public enum GrannyPet
{
    // Enum objects, automatically instantiated when this class loads.
    TWEETY( new Bird() ),
    SYLVESTER( new Cat() ),
    HECTOR( new Dog() );

    // Member variables.
    private Animal animal;

    // Constructor
    GrannyPet ( Animal animalArg )
    {
        this.animal = animalArg;
    }

    // Accessor, getter.
    public Animal getAnimal ()
    {
        return this.animal;
    }

}
```

Lastly, we revise our code calling the enum from this:

```
grannyPet.speak()
```

…to this:

```
grannyPet.getAnimal().speak()
```

That calling code looks like this:

```
    Set < GrannyPet > grannyPets = EnumSet.allOf( GrannyPet.class );
    for ( GrannyPet grannyPet : grannyPets )
    {
        System.out.println( "Granny’s pet: " + grannyPet + " says: " + grannyPet.getAnimal().speak() );
    }
```

When run.

> Granny’s pet: TWEETY says: chirp
>
> Granny’s pet: SYLVESTER says: meow
>
> Granny’s pet: HECTOR says: bark